# Disabled cookies - is it a viable use case to relate to?

Tags: use-cases, cookies

Disabled cookies - is it a viable use case to relate to?

i.e. users reaching a website with disabled cookies, should i tailor a code case for them?
Notify them that they cannot use the site w/o cookies enabled? 
Link to an explanation etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a matter of gradation:

- If the functional difference between Users having cookies enabled and those who have them disabled is non-significant, I would only **display a message that it is suggested to have cookies enabled.**
- In case there is a significant increase of functionality with cookies enabled, I would additionally **give them possibility to access an extended information about it** (e.g. what will work and what will not in this case).
- I would only disallow Users to use the site **if using it with cookies disabled would severely affect the site functionality**.

However "significant" and "severely" depend are something to approach differently in each case and I believe you need to answer which is which yourself. Or ask your users.